# Switch case on parameter value in Kettle?

Tags: switch-statement, pentaho, kettle

I have a number of boolean parameters defined for my Kettle transformation. Now I would like to do a switch case based on the value of a parameter. So if `Parameter A` is true, all rows should be routed to `Step 1`, and if it is false rows should be routed to `Step 2`. The switch case step does not seem to support this, as it only switches on field names. The same seems to be the case for the filter rows step.

Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That all depends on the scope you're working in.
If it's a transformation, then you can get the variables into a column in the data set. Downside - the parameter's value won't change, but the Switch-Case step will still check it for every row, which is **highly inefficient**, but there are other ways to improve on that (e.g. using a **User Defined Java Class** instead, implementing the switch in Java only for the first row in the stream):

[image: KTR example]

If it's a job scope you're referring to, then just implement the switch-case as a stream of variable evaluation:

[image: KJB example]